# How to read all the available data from a WinRT StreamSocket and empty the inputStream?

Tags: javascript, sockets, asynchronous, windows-runtime

I want to read all the data that is currently waiting on a socket before writing new data to it.
The reading methods in WinRT are all async so I cannot simply `while` until the socket is empty.
Since I do want to discard the data on the socket, I do not want to use a reader, but straight read the data from the `IInputStream` of the socket.

Something like this pseudo code:

```
function emptySocket(inputStream, timeout, buffer) {
  if (!buffer) {
    buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(4096);
  }
  WinJS.Promise.timeout(timeout, inputStream.readAsync(buffer, 4096, Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.partial)
  .then(function(buffer) {
    if (buffer.length === 0) return;
    emptySocket(inputStream, timeout, buffer);
  }), function (error) {
    return;
  });
}
```

The timeout is there to break the wait operation when nothing is on the socket any more. `Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.partial` does not seem to return if nothing is on the socket.

btw: Whats the difference between `Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.partial` and `Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.readAhead`?

Comment: The `IInputStream` won't return zero bytes, unless the stream/connection is over.

`partial` reads anything between 1 to `count` bytes, and returns as soon as it has some data. `readAhead` reads `count` or more bytes if more data is available, and return when there are at least `count` bytes. The last `readAhead` call can return less than `count` bytes if the stream is over.

Comment: This means the only way to terminate the wait for new bytes is to use a timeout?

Comment: Or could I use `readAhead` with `count=0` to read at least 0 bytes?

Comment: The problem with cancelling the `readAsync` operation is that it closes the underlying socket :( So is there really no equivalent to the old Winsock ioctlsocket?

Comment: You may be interested in reading [Avoid Data Peeking in Winsock](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192599)

Comment: Yes I understand that. I am not a fan of polling. I prefer the async way. However I need to empty the socket and not wait forever for new bytes.