# Read InputStream asynchronously

Tags: c#, inputstream

I'm trying to receive packets and if no bytes are received continue with the code below. *await ReadAsync* blocks until a new packet is received. Is there any way to just read the current bytes received?

If I don't use *await* messages aren't received.

```
byte[] data = new byte[BufferSize];

IInputStream inputStream = socket.InputStream;
IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();

socketInformation.GetStopwatchPingIdleTime().Start();

while (socketInformation.open)
{
    try
    {
        inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
        data = buffer.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        break;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        // Wait for payload size
        if (buffer.Length >= 4)
        {
            int commandType = (int)BitConverter.ToInt16(data, 0);
            int payloadSize = (int)BitConverter.ToInt16(data, 2);
            int packetSize = PacketHeaderSize + payloadSize;

            // Wait for a full message
            if (buffer.Length >= packetSize)
            {
                byte[] packet = new byte[packetSize];
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, packet, 0, packetSize);

                ParsePacketSequence(socket, socketInformation, packet);

                if (buffer.Length > packetSize)
                {
                    int bufferLength = (int)buffer.Length - packetSize;

                    byte[] newData = new byte[BufferSize];
                    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, packetSize, newData, 0, bufferLength);
                    data = newData;

                    buffer.Length = (uint)bufferLength;
                }
                else if (buffer.Length == packetSize)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (buffer.Length == packetSize)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (host)
    {
        // Send ping to player
        if (socketInformation.waitingPong == false && 
            socketInformation.GetStopwatchPingIdleTime().ElapsedMilliseconds > 5000)
        {
            byte[] pingPacket = CreatePacket(6, null);
            SendPacket(socket, socketInformation, pingPacket);

            socketInformation.waitingPong = true;
        }
    }

    await Task.Delay(33, tokenSource.Token);
}

inputStream.Dispose();
socket.Dispose();
tokenSource.Cancel();
```

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533703/how-to-read-all-the-available-data-from-a-winrt-streamsocket-and-empty-the-input

Comment: This approach is very problematic. I do not see how it can be fixed even. Can you elaborate what you want to accomplish so that we can recommend a different approach?

Comment: For example there is no way to "empty a stream". One ms after you declare it empty a new byte might arrive.

Comment: @usr I want to check if there are bytes available to read, if there is nothing just continue the loop and check again when the loops restarts.

Comment: So I assume you want to read a message? What if the first byte of the message arrives and the rest arrives 10 seconds later? What do you want to do then?

Comment: @usr Append to the buffer, I think that the buffer gets cleared when new bytes are received but that's another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me you are receiving a stream of messages. When a message is there you want to process it potentially at some later time or at a different place in the code.

A good approach for that is to have one `Task` continuously reading messages from the socket and putting them into a queue. You can then pull complete messages from the queue whenever you like.

That way you can get rid of most of the logic here. You never have to abort a read request and you never need to check for timeouts.