# How to know whether the socket connection is still alive when using StreamSocket in UWP?

Tags: c#, sockets, win-universal-app

I am using `StreamSocket` to connect to a socket server and I use a infinite loop to read data. Each piece of data ends with `'\n\n'`. The snippet is shown below. However, I can't know whether the socket is still alive, and every time the server shuts down the connection, `ReadAsync()` throws exception. How to be notified when the connection is closed?

```
public async Task<string> ReadData() {
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());
    char[] ch = new char[65536];
    int i = 0;
    while (IsConnected) {
        await reader.ReadAsync(ch, i++, 1);
        if (i > 1 && ch[i - 1] == '\n' && ch[i - 2] == '\n') break;
    }
    return new StringBuilder().Append(ch, 0, i - 2).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# detecting tcp disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067014/c-sharp-detecting-tcp-disconnect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and every time the server shuts down the connection, ReadAsync() throws exception.

The exception is thrown because an **ungraceful disconnect** occurs. So make sure there is **no any pending read or write operations** exist on the socket before shutting down the connection on the server side, then there should be no exception. You can refer to the Remarks part of [StreamSocket class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226882) for more details.

> How to be notified when the connection is closed?

A graceful socket closure can be detected by the other side as a 0-length read. That is, it just acts like a regular end-of-stream. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096462/handling-winrt-streamsocket-disconnects-both-server-and-client-side) is a similar thread for your reference.

So you can use the following code to check if the connection is closed in your scenario:

```
// break when the connection is closed
if (ch[i - 1] == '\0') break;
```

Following is the entire method I have verified:

```
public async Task<string> ReadData()
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());
    char[] ch = new char[65536];
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        await reader.ReadAsync(ch, i++, 1);
        // break when the connection is closed or data ends with '\n\n'
        if (ch[i - 1] == '\0' || (i > 1 && ch[i - 1] == '\n' && ch[i - 2] == '\n')) break;
    }

    if (ch[i - 1] == '\0')
    {
        // do something here when the connection is closed
    }
    else
    {
        return new StringBuilder().Append(ch, 0, i - 2).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> every time the server shuts down the connection, ReadAsync() throws exception.

This is to be expected for most servers. TCP/IP has a rather expensive *four-part* handshake to gracefully close a connection, but from the server's perspective, that's a long time to wait to reclaim those resources. So, a lot of servers just "slam" the connection shut, causing a `SocketError.ConnectionReset` error.

As I describe in my [socket error handling](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/error-handling.html) blog post, if the communication state is such that you would consider a "graceful close" appropriate at that point, then you should also accept an exception with `ConnectionReset` at the same point. (In your case, the appropriate "close" point is if the message has completed with a `\n\n`).

> How to be notified when the connection is closed?

You will either get a `ConnectionReset` exception (if it is abruptly closed), or your `ReadAsync` will return `0` (if it is gracefully closed).

However...

> How to know whether the socket connection is still alive?

There is only one reliable way to detect whether a socket connection is still viable: *write* data to it. I cover this in detail in my blog post on the [half-open problem](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html).

Because of this rather interesting quirk in socket communications, code like `while (IsConnected)` is an anti-pattern. Instead, you need to have a regular polling loop that *sends* data to the other side based on a timer.

P.S. If at all possible, use SignalR instead of raw sockets. They do all the hard stuff for you.